# XmlHttpRequest2 progress event and ExtJS 3.3 Ext.Ajax

Tags: ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, progress, extjs3

I'm trying to use [XmlHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) to create a file upload page which includes a progress bar, in a fashion similar to [a tutorial I found on Matlus.com](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/).

The catch is, the page I'm working on has to be added to an existing [ExtJs 3](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs3/) application.

How can I manipulate the `XmlHttpRequest` objects which are created by `Ext.Ajax`, so I can add event listeners for `"progress"`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the code, Ext.Ajax.request actually returns a hashmap, not a number like the documentation suggests. You should be able to get the XMLHttpRequest object by referencing Ext.Ajax.request(...).conn and calling addEventListener on that.